# How to capture the event of changing a file in a folder?

Tags: bash, shell, unix

Will there be any event generated when the contents of a folder in UNIX is changed(removed, added or edited), and can this event be captured to trigger another script?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using Linux, you can use the [inotify](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) subsystem to catch this sort thing.  There are `inotify` bindings for Python, Perl, and so forth, or you can use the `inotifywait` program (part of the [inotify-tools](http://inotify-tools.sourceforge.net/) package) in shell scripts.

For example, if I run `inotifywait -m /tmp`, this will watch `/tmp` for changes.  If I create a file, I see:

```
/tmp/ CREATE foo
/tmp/ OPEN foo
/tmp/ ATTRIB foo
/tmp/ CLOSE_WRITE,CLOSE foo
```

And if I delete that file, I see:

```
/tmp/ DELETE foo
```

You can write a shell script that reads these notifications from `inotifywait` and acts on them accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I made use of inotify.h header file to create a C program that listens for a change in the folder.